# Google graph - stretch graph over x and y labels

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, google-visualization

I'm designing graph using `google graph`. I have no need for labes on x and y axis, so I hidden them by setting the following options:

```
var options = {
    hAxis: {
        baselineColor: 'none',
        ticks: [],       
        position: 'none',
        fontsize: 0 // do not do anything
    },
    vAxis: {
        baselineColor: 'none',
        ticks: [],       
        position: 'none',
        fontsize: 0 // do not do anything
    }
};
```

My chart currently look like this:

[image]

I would like to stretch it to the full width and height of element. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `chartArea` option...

```
var options = {
  chartArea: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
  },
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%',
  ...
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['X', 'Y'],
    [0, 5],
    [1, 6],
    [2, 7],
    [3, 5]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
    },
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    hAxis: {
        baselineColor: 'none',
        ticks: [],
        position: 'none',
        fontsize: 0 // do not do anything
    },
    vAxis: {
        baselineColor: 'none',
        ticks: [],
        position: 'none',
        fontsize: 0 // do not do anything
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```